# Unable to build cordova project for android

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, gradle

I'm not cordova/android expert. I was provided with build steps to build some cordova project. However they stopped working after quite some time. I'm using old cordova 6.5.0 to build a cordova project for android. I don't believe i've changed any setup or libraries. I deleted my android studio and android sdk and installed them again. And Now i'm getting lots of weird errors like:

1. When i do cordova build android

```
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
Error: Error
    at /platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:313:19
    at _fulfilled (XXX/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (XXX/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (XXX/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at XXX/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:877:14
    at runSingle (XXX/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (XXX/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:95:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
```

I do have ANDROID_HOME:

```
/root/Android/Sdk
```

and $PATH:

```
echo $PATH
/home/XXX/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/home/XXX/dev/tools/idea-IU-145.258.11/bin:/root/Android/Sdk/tools:/root/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/XXX/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/4.4.1/bin
```

I tried building it with android studio, supplying various version of gradle, but i always get stuck with some weird errors.

How can i understand what have happened? What versions of which libs i suould use?

Thanks